# switching from Programmatically to StoryBoard (in XCode) as fast as possible

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I had moved from a company that was developing iOS applications using Programmatically branch of coding to a new one witch use StoryBoard style.

im not familiar with StoryBoards or XIB neither !!!

im not able to understand the code handover witch i received in the last two days, i want to learn StoryBoard as soon as possible,
i tried to search the web for some good tutorials but i didn't find much.

i had read so far:

[Tutorial from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)

[Another from raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

and [Another from appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/)

Please advice, thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing is too basic when you don't have any idea about the subject. And, what's 'XIP'?

Comment: XIB for user interface

Comment: Oh, then it should be 'XIB', I guess.

Comment: have a look to youtube tutorials on storyboard. i have learnt from them

Comment: @VivekSehrawat actually i didn't, because i prefer to read more than watch, but i will consider your suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The Big Nerd Ranch "iOS Programming" book has a chapter on Storyboards that I at least found useful. It's a little dated (next edition coming soon) but still mostly relevant.

Comment: How to get this book?

Comment: At your favorite Ebook store?

Comment: I used it on the Kindle, but yeah I'd imagine it's available from numerous ebook stores